# Array in functions Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

can someone tell me what is this code doing, As im new to Yii, learning about it.. im not able to understand few things.. Here is the code..

```
$allmsg = LogMsg::model()->findAll($criteria); // 
    $dataArr = array();
    if (isset($allMsg) && sizeof($allMsg) != 0):
        foreach ($allMsg as $msg) {
            $dataArr[$msg->date][] = array( // array?
                'category' => $msg->category, // what is that 'category' a variable or something else? and $msg->category, is what?
                'time' => $msg->time,
                'date' => $msg->date,
                'user' => $msg->name
            );
        }   endif; 
$this->render('index', array(
            'data' => $dataArr ) //what is that 'data'?
    );
```

My question is, what is this line of code doing exactly in foreach loop

```
$dataArr[$msg->date][] = array(
                'category' => $msg->category,
```

and here is second code... which has something like that..

```
$allCat = Categories::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $catArr=array();
    if(isset($allCat) && sizeof($allCat)!=0):
        foreach ($allCat as $catModel) {
            $catArr[$catModel->id] =$catModel;
        }
    endif;
    return $catArr;
```

so what is this line doing in this code in foreach loop, what is different between these two lines in first and second code..

```
$catArr[$catModel->id] =$catModel;
```

last thing.. what is it

```
    public static function getID($category)
{
    $arr = array(
        'ast'=>1, // what are these things? from where are they coming? db?
        'fp'=>5, //
        'per'=>3, 
        'ts'=>6,
        'lg'=>3
    );
    return isset($arr[$category])?$arr[$category]:null;  //Ternary - Condensed if/else statement
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is creating multidimensional array.

Your first question

```
$dataArr[$msg->date][] = array(
                'category' => $msg->category,
```

will generate output like

```
[2016-03-04] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => abc
                )

        )
```

And your second question

```
$catArr[$catModel->id] =$catModel;
```

will genrate output like

```
array(
     [0] =>1,
    [1] => 2,
    [2] => 3,
)
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

So as per your first question.

`$dataArr[$msg->date][] = array(
                'category' => $msg->category,`

$allMsg is the active record object which u get through the db query. This object is traversed in a loop and each row is "$msg".

Hence you can access the attributes of the model through the $msg->category. `'category'` here is the attribute of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your question is not about Yii. You should read about [arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) of PHP first. In the code [multidimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp) have been used. It means that the array can contain another array as value.